# In pentaho reports how can I create a report with multiple queries?

Tags: java, pentaho

I
 have three tables each one has a date field and some statistics saved in a number of other fields. I want in a single report, side by side, to disply for each day the statistics data found in each table.

```
     Table 1              Table2              Table3
     Date   Stat1 Stat2 stat3   Stat1 Stat2 Stat3    Stat1 Stat2
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Create query for each report(while in master report view)
2. Create 3 in-line sub-reports in "Report Header" section (not the details section), place side-by-side
3. In sub-report design view , select the right query and design as usual, just don't add any detail headers.
4. Place your detail headers in the "Page Header" section of the main report not in the sub-report (so they can repeat through the pages, otherwise they won't)

Comment: THank You So much... This solution worked for me :) @Yazan Jaber